# Query DB2 using collation

Tags: db2, collation

Is it possible to perform a query in DB2 and specify a collation to use?

In SQL Server it's fairly common to do

SELECT Column1
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'casesearch'

It's about IBM DB2 LUW.

Comment: Which which member of the DB2 family (which OS type) are you asking about -- DB2 for i, LUW (Linux-Unix-Windows), or z/OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly like this, but check if the `COLLATION_KEY_BIT()` function will work for you: [Manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050491.html)

Your code then will look something like

```
SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 
WHERE 
 COLLATION_KEY_BIT(Column1, 'SYSTEM_1252') =  
 COLLATION_KEY_BIT('casesearch', 'SYSTEM_1252')
```